# Binding a checkbox in a datagrid header

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a datagrid where the first column contains a checkbox to let the user selects specific rows. I have added a checkbox in the datagrid column header to check or uncheck all the rows.

Is it possible to add this functionality only with binding in XAML (no checked event).

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1"  Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding myCollection.UserSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkAll" IsThreeState="True"  
                                              IsChecked="{Binding myCollection.UserSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource threeStateConverter}}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Chemin" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

I think there's something wrong with the "myCollection.UserSelected" part. `ThreeStateConverter` is a value converter that would return null when some items are selected, true when they are all selected, etc. but the `Convert` method is never called (even though the `PropertyChanged` event is raised when `UserSelected` is changed).

Any idea on how I can do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you've solved the problem already, but nevertheless:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <model:MyModel x:Key="Model"/>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
...    
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" >
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="datap:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Margin="2,0,-13,0" DataContext="{StaticResource Model}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AllChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`MyModel` class contains `bool?` property that implements logic of selection. It is also used as a `DataContext of page.

I must admit that this potentially has problems if we need to change model.

EDIT: I found another way:

```
<navigation:Page.DataContext>
    <model:MyModel />
</navigation:Page.DataContext>
...    
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" >
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="datap:DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Margin="2,0,-13,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllChecked, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here we bind to `DataContext` of root layout element (usually called `LayoutRoot`) which inherits its data context from page by default.