# Is there any way to add checkbox to all column headers inside datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have listbox containing datagrid that is binded to a datatable in the following way:

In code behind:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(dt1);
```

Here dt is the table name.

**In Xaml:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="305" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="537" >            
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
                <DataTemplate>                    
                        <StackPanel MinHeight="80" MinWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" MinHeight="75" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="470" MaxWidth="900" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                            </DataGrid>
                            <CheckBox  Grid.Column="0" Height="35" Width="25" Name="IsDone" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>                        
                    </StackPanel>                   
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want to add check box to all column headers present in datagrid. Can you please suggest me how to add checkboxes to all column headers present inside datagrid in Wpf

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't mark it entirely as a duplicate, but you'll get the jist [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335762/binding-a-checkbox-in-a-datagrid-header) about just using `HeaderStyle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `ColumnHeaderStyle` for your DataGrid and in that set the `ContentTemplate` to have checkboxes for all headers like this:

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```